# how to make a PHP file run-able only through CLI mode?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

It's available to browser,

but I don't want it to execute when browsed by user,

say,when browsed should exit,

is there a way to detect whether it's currently Cmmand Line Mode?

Answer (score 12):

Here is what i'm using, for a long time now... (since php 4 iirc)

```
(PHP_SAPI !== 'cli' || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) && die('cli only');
```

to be used as first line of the php script.

Comment: This has always been the perfect solution!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick:

You can check for the $argc/$argv parameters which are always available in CLI mode.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php 

ini_set('register_argc_argv', 0);  

if (!isset($argc) || is_null($argc))
{ 
    echo 'Not CLI mode';
} else {
    echo 'CLI mode';
}
```

[register_argc_argv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv)

[$argc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php)

Comment: Why fiddle with INI settings when php_sapi_name() is designed for exactly this purpose?

Comment: There is another problem,use this way,when debugging in Zend,it's also treated as "Not CLI mode" even when it is actually

Answer (score 2):

Another trick, `$_SERVER` has variables that are only set in CLI mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!defined('STDIN')) {
    // accessed through the web browser
    die();
}
```

I use this when creating PHP CLI scripts. Works very well.